# minimizing a concave function

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, approximation, linearization, convexity-inequality

After decoupling a big optimization, the inner one is as follow:

$min_X \quad log_2 \left(det(A+BX\right))$

$s.t. norm(X)\leq \gamma,$

where $A\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ and $B\in \mathbb{C}^{n\times m}$ are known, while $X\in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ includes optimization variables. As you can see the problem became minimization of a concave function. To avoid search on boundaries, I decided to linearize  $det\left(A+BX\right)$ and ignore $log_2()$.

I appreciate any hint about linearization of $det\left(A+BX\right)$ in its general form without any assumption on $A$, $B$, or $BX$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula

Comment: @Lin thanks for your quick and valuable help. Could you please explain a bit more about your idea of using Jacobi's formula for linearization? I'm sorry for this noobish request.

Comment: For a first order Taylor approximatino you just need the derivative, right?

Comment: Yes, you are completely right.  But, if I use the first order Taylor expansion, the tangent point, i.e., the point I am approximating the function around that, should be very close to the optimal point. How can I have that luxury!? I know minorization-majorization algorithm can help to iteratively use first-order Taylor and reach optimal point, but I don't want to go for iterative approaches. Do you agree with my perception?

Comment: yes, but to linearize a function close to the optimal point, you need to know where the optimal point is approximately, so I do not see what method you have in mind; also looking at the problem, what happens if the determinant is nonpositive?

Comment: Oh, I see your concern. There are some underlying features that prevents negative or zero determinant. As my last question, do you think I can use Jacobi's formula for my complex matrices? I really appreciate your valuable time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110083/discussion-between-zstr-and-linalg).